# Leer una variable y cargarla como parámetro de una subproceso

Tags: c, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente registo o estructura que define variables referentes a los productos utilizados en, por ejemplo, una fábrica.

```
typedef enum {IMPORTADO, LOCAL} tipo;

typedef struct
{
    int codigo;
    char descripcion [20];
    char unidadMedida [5];
    float precio;
    tipo discriminante;
    union
    {
        char origen [20];
        char destino [20];
        int telefono;
    } impoExpo;
} Producto;    

void cargarProducto (Producto *p)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el c¢digo: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->codigo);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese la descripci¢n: ");
    scanf("%s",p->descripcion);
    printf("Indique la unidad de medida: ");
    scanf("%s",p->unidadMedida);
    printf("Ingrese el precio: ");
    scanf("%f",&p->precio);
    int i;
    printf("\nInqrese 1 si es importado");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        p->discriminante = IMPORTADO;
    }
    else
    {
        p->discriminante = LOCAL;
    }
    if(p->discriminante == IMPORTADO)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese al origen: ");
        gets(p->impoExpo.origen);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nIngrese el telefono");
        scanf("%d", &p->impoExpo.telefono);
    }
}

void mostrarProducto (Producto p)
{
    printf("\nC¢digo: %d", p.codigo);
    printf("\nDescripci¢n ");
    printf("%s", p.descripcion);
    printf("\nUnidad de medida: ");
    printf("%s", p.unidadMedida);
    printf("\nPrecio: %.2f", p.precio);
    printf("\nTipo: ");
    if (p.discriminante == IMPORTADO)
    {
        printf("Importado: ");
        printf("\nOrigen: %s",p.impoExpo.origen);
        printf("%s",p.impoExpo.origen);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Local: ");
        printf("\nTelefono: %d", p.impoExpo.telefono);
    }
}
```

Quiero cargar la variable p al procedimento cargar producto

```
int main()
{
    int opcion;
    do
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("Bienvenido al programa\n");
        printf("Ingrese una opcion\n");
        printf("1. Cargar un producto\n");
        printf("2. Mostrar producto\n");
        printf("3. Verificar si dos productos son iguales\n");
        printf("0. Salir");
        printf("Ingrese la opci¢n, y presione ENTER");
        scanf("%d",&opcion);

        switch(opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            cargarProducto(Producto.p);
            getch();
            break;
        case 2:
            mostrarProducto(Producto.p);
            getch();
            break;
```

cuando hago esto el compliador dice: error: expected expression before 'Producto' ¿como se carga la variable correctamente?

Comment: No se porque cada vez veo mas este error de usar un tipo como una variable, ya estoy pensando en crear una respuesta canonica y empezar a marcar duplicados. `Producto` es un tipo, es un alias a un `struct` anonimo. Tu lo estas usando como si fuera una variable. Lo solucionas creado una variable (`Producto p;`), y usando eso.

Comment: Yo es la primera vez que lo veo. Pero está bueno crear una respuesta canonica

Comment: No use [gets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/), en su lugar, utilice [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).